# Show bootstrap alert when email field is not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an website and i need to inform the user when he clicks the "reset your Password" line to enter his email in the respective field. I've checked the bootstrap documentation and they only presents the HTML code for a drop-down alert... it does run when the page loads but i only want to show the alert when the phrase is clicked. Check the code below....

```
            <button type="submit" name="go" id="connect_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" tabindex="4" >Sign In</button>
            <div>
                <a id="signup_btn" href="../signup.php">Create an Account</a>
                    <div>
                        <a id="forgetpwd_btn" href="#" onclick="submitForm('../actions/process_forgetpwd.php');">Reset your Password</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

I know the best way to do this is by doing a js, but unfortunately i have really low experience on them.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: So what you want to verify is if the user types his e-mail before clicking on the button ? It's a bit unclear what you want.

Comment: Yes. The "process_forgetpwd.php" needs the email as an input. So when the user clicks the "Forgot my Password" link the email needs to be filled.

Comment: See if my answer fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<input type="email" ..... required>
```

The required attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

It's not an alert but a message is displayed to the user notifying if the input does not match an e-mail (@) or if he is missing the field.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to add a class whenever the form submission happens? U could just deal with the dropdown alert by adding and removing the class, such as

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

However, if you wish to show alert boxes, then you can try intergrating this:
http://bootboxjs.com/

Its a very simple library that gives you lots of inbuild features.

Comment: Or you could simply write element.style.display= none;